# Java LDAP graceful disconnect

Tags: java, connection, ldap

Currently from java I am connecting to LDAP with the following code, very typical example:

```
    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();

    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, user);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

    LdapContext ctx = null;

    try
    {
        ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
        return true;
    }
    catch (NamingException ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (ctx != null)
        {
            try {
                ctx.close();
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                log.warn(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

This works in terms of authenticating the user. However the LDAP administrator is telling me that I am not disconnecting gracefully when the bind is not successful. The error on the LDAP side is (e.g.):

> [24/Jan/2013:13:20:44 -0500] conn=249 op=-1 msgId=-1 - closing from [ipaddress]:44724 - A1 - Client aborted connection -

He also says when it is a successful authentication, the disconnection is graceful. I guess this is because I do the `ctx.close()` in that situation.

However, when authentication fails, there's actually an exception thrown from the `new InitialLdapContext(env, null)` line. Therefore no context is returned, and no close is called on any context.

Is there some way to retrieve some kind of connection object, before attempting the authentication, so that I can close it afterwards whether or not auth was successful?

Comment: finally blocks are always executed, even if an exception is thrown in the try or any of the catches. I do wonder about your return. You may want to log the NamingException and move your return false to the outside of the try/catch/finally block.

Comment: @ErikNedwidek Yes, but `ctx` will always be null in this case. Note that finally is executed even when a return statement is requested - it's done before returning. @user2009267 - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/ldap.html implies that for LDAP v3 you can add authentication afterwards - whether anonymous authentication and then adding the context later solves your problem I don't know.

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse - thanks. Do you mean the part where they use `ctx.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "none");`? I don't think this can be used to authenticate a "new" user. I've only seen authentication done via the `new IntialContext(..)` call.

@ErikNedwidek as Philip says, the finally block will simply get executed before the return. But in the case of an exception from the `new InitialContext` call, `ctx` is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why does he care between a graceful and non-graceful close? Clearly your close is being executed in the only relevant case: the case where you succeeded. In the other case there is nothing to close, so nothing you can call. The JNDI LDAP provider closes it in the other case, and clearly it is that which is doing the abortive close. This is all under the hood in the JNDI LDAP provider. Nothing you can do about it. I suggest he find something else to worry about that's actually important.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the option to tell him otherwise. I've been told this requirement must be met as per the company security policy. You know how it is with those security guys. And technically it's not being closed in all cases as when the authentication fails, the `new InitialContext(..)` call actually throws a NamingException -- meaning no `ctx` is returned, and the `finally` block has nothing to call `close()` on. I guess this is why the connection gets "aborted".

Comment: @user2009267 See edit, but there's still nothing you can do about it. What security aspect does an abortive TCP close have? There are plenty of other clients that do it, for example Internet Explorer. The only thing I can suggest is that you enable JNDi connection pooling via the appropriate properties: see the LDAP Provider page for details. It might change the behaviour: it might not.

Comment: i know it's been just about two years since this question, but i had forgotten about it and stumbled back on it. it turns out this answer by EJP was closest to the truth. We kept insisting that the API didn't seem to allow for closes in that situation and they eventually stopped bothering us about it. To this day the code remains as it was in my example. Not sure if there actually is a better solution out there.

Comment: after closing the context, and reconnecting (i am buliding a kinda "is connection possible"-script for some monitoring) "currentconnections" from "cn=monitor" showed increasing connections (until closing those between 15 and 20 opened connections)

The right answer is to close the result too:
results.close();
This helped reducing open connections on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Searching LDAP normally returns

```
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results
```

which you also need to close():

```
} finally {
            if(results != null) {
                try {
                    results.close();
                } catch (NamingException e) {
                    LOG.error("Error closing LDAP results", e);
                }
            }
```

Comment: i have already added ctx.close() function but i just want to confirm if the connection is closed or not. is there any way for that?

Answer (score 0):

Construct the context object before adding any authentication details. Then, use addToEnvironment to add in the credentials. Finally, perform a very simple search (My approach is to lookup the username's distinguishedName attribute). The search will fail if the credentials aren't good, and you'll still have a context object to close.

An added bonus of this approach: you can maintain a pool of context objects and avoid constantly connecting/disconnecting to perform authentication.

```
Hashtable<String,String> environment = new Hashtable<String,String>();
environment.put("java.naming.provider.url", url);
environment.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");

InitialLdapContext context = new InitialLdapContext(environment, null);

...

context.addToEnvironment("java.naming.security.principal", principal);
context.addToEnvironment("java.naming.security.credentials", credentials);

...

// execute some kind of search, based on your needs
```

Comment: If anybody knows how to force re-auth without actually searching, I'd love to know how it's done!